# Can't access method on same class

Tags: php, oop

I don't understand the logic on this, I get an error that my function convertBinToMSSQLGuid can't be found. I know that it doesn't make sense the coding, it is for testing purposes. Also tried making it private, no luck.

```
class PowerBiResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
       dd(convertBinToMSSQLGuid($this->VehicleID));
       return '';
    }
    public function convertBinToMSSQLGuid($binguid)
    {
       $unpacked = unpack('Va/v2b/n2c/Nd',$binguid);
       return sprintf('%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%08X', $unpacked['a'], $unpacked['b1'], $unpacked['b2'], $unpacked['c1'], $unpacked['c2'], $unpacked['d']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly access any custom class function by direct name. You can access as below:

```
class PowerBiResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
       dd($this->convertBinToMSSQLGuid($this->VehicleID));
       return '';
    }
    public function convertBinToMSSQLGuid($binguid)
    {
       $unpacked = unpack('Va/v2b/n2c/Nd',$binguid);
       return sprintf('%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%08X', $unpacked['a'], $unpacked['b1'], $unpacked['b2'], $unpacked['c1'], $unpacked['c2'], $unpacked['d']);
    }
}
```

You can use the function by refering `$this->`. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling `convertBinToMSSQLGuid` from inside its class, you must use `$this->`:

```
dd($this->convertBinToMSSQLGuid($this->VehicleID));
```